# Is it a good practice to call third party api before every controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, warden

is it a good practice if we can call a REST api on `before_action` hook of `application_controller.rb` and store the response in helper method?

My Scenario is that I wanna call an API from another app and get its data for a specific user role after that user is signed in. I am using Warden gem and I also have its `after_authentication` hook to do that but how do I make sure to use that API response in my app (i.e helpers/views/controllers etc).

I am having a bad feeling to do it on every request, I need to know if there could be a pattern or any better approach that solves these kind of problems.

Comment: If you are calling third party api before every request then its definately not a good practice. What i suggest is do only one api call for your first request. then after save that data into your database. Ask that third party whether they provide any webhook service to update the existing data.

Comment: it would be great if you use a webhook in these situations and also can you please elaborate your requirement in detail?

Comment: Thanks @Vishal. That's great to store it in DB but unfortunately there are no webhooks setup on the third party app. So is there a way I could check if the stored API data is always latest?